# XmlValidatingReader class is obsolete

Tags: xml, xsd

I am using  XmlValidatingReader object to validat my object against a xsd schema but this class is obsolete in .NEt 2.0. Does any one have the right code to use the new Vaildation classes.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes:

```
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();

settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
settings.Schemas.Add ( .... );
settings.ValidationEventHandler += delegate( object sender, ValidationEventArgs e )
{
    Console.WriteLine("invalid: " + e.Message);
};

XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create (new XmlTextReader(file), settings);
```

Answer (score -3):

Check the MSDN documentation for XmlValidatingReader and you'll see in the [ObsoleteAttribute] attribute this:

"Use XmlReader created by XmlReader.Create() method using appropriate XmlReaderSettings instead. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=14202"

Comment: How could this be an answer? It's exactly the message you already got from Visual Studio!

Comment: I agree with @edc65