# "Circular attribute group reference."

Tags: c#, xml, iis, xsd-validation

Its the weird-weird situation once again :)

I've function that verifies given XML against XSD and throws exception when the validation fails. (the function is called from WebPage that receives the xml calls)

both the call

```
if (!xmlvld.ValidXmlDoc(X, "", "https://somepathtofile.xsd")) 
    throw new Exception(xmlvld.ValidationError + "1");
```

and the validating function are pretty simple

```
   /// <summary>
    /// This method validates an xml string against an xml schema.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="xml">StringReader containing xml</param>
    /// <param name="schemaNamespace">XML Schema Namespace</param>
    /// <param name="schemaUri">XML Schema Uri</param>
    /// <returns>bool</returns>
    public bool ValidXmlDoc(StringReader xml, string schemaNamespace, string schemaUri)
    {
        // Continue?
        if (xml == null || schemaNamespace == null || schemaUri == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        isValidXml = true;
        XmlValidatingReader vr;
        XmlTextReader tr;
        XmlSchemaCollection schemaCol = new XmlSchemaCollection();
        schemaCol.Add(schemaNamespace, schemaUri);

        try
        {
            // Read the xml.
            tr = new XmlTextReader(xml);
            // Create the validator.
            vr = new XmlValidatingReader(tr);
            // Set the validation tyep.
            vr.ValidationType = ValidationType.Auto;
            // Add the schema.
            if (schemaCol != null)
            {
                vr.Schemas.Add(schemaCol);
            }
            // Set the validation event handler.
            vr.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationCallBack);
            // Read the xml schema.
            while (vr.Read())
            {
            }

            vr.Close();

            return isValidXml;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.ValidationError = ex.Message;
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            // Clean up...
            vr = null;
            tr = null;
        }
    }
```

And this worked very well for the last 2 years, but recently the validation function started to return the follwing message:

```
[ValidationError]Circular attribute group reference.[/ValidationError]
```

Which is false message - neither the XSD nor the sent XML have changed, furthermore if I recycle the Application Pool, and send the same XML again (I've "ping" program that sends the same XML every few seconds and checks the result) the validation passes... for a while (some is between few minutes and few hours).

The XSD is sitting in the same directory as the calling page and in the server log I see the request to the XSD with HTTP/200 response, I even tried changeing the HTTPS to local path but the error remained the same (pointing to invalid address gives HTTP/404 or invalid path exceptions so it does attempt to read the XSD file)

Again - recycling the apppool resolves it immediately but I can't recycle every 5 mins.

Thanks in advance!
Simon

Comment: A sample of your xml and the xsd would help.

Comment: What triggers the validation?  How often does this occur?

Comment: @Kev - Example of the XML ans XSD is the one think I can't upload, and yet, as I wrote - both the XSD and the XML are fine - after recycling the app-pool both of them work fine.
@James B - The validation is preformed everytime XML request is received, aprox. 100 times/minute

Comment: Mulling it over... can you post the callback code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't like this answer, but apparently the `XmlValidatingReader` was obsoleted in .NET 2.0... perhaps because of issues like this?

The suggestion is to [validate using an `XmlReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdf992b8%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).  That link is for the 2.0 version of the help files, which includes some details specific to converting from an `XmlValidatingReader`; more recent versions of the help are available from the drop-down at the top.

[This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlvalidatingreader.read.aspx) gives details about the `XmlValidatingReader` being obsolete.

An example of using an `XmlReader` is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630641/xmlvalidatingreader-class-is-obsolete).

Comment: Sorry for the delay - you are right. I don't like it but you are right.